# What are the correct settings for EFCore.Design package in the csproj file, to ensure migrations will work and the pjt will build?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Using .net Core 3.1. My solution has 2 projects, .Web (front end) and .Data which has the models and DbContext.

the .Data project csproj file includes these lines:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.2">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

If I try to run the ef core migrations Update-Database command, I get an error saying my startup project (.Web) does not contain a reference to EFCore.Design.

If I remove this line, it works:

```
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
```

But removing that line causes the yellow dependencies triangle in visual studio, indicating a problem.  The project builds and runs, but no one likes yellow triangles.

**Question**

How should my csproj file be configured to both allow ef core migrations to run, and not have yellow dependency problem triangles in my solution expolorer?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove both the privateassests and includeassests tags.